# How do i find the highest number in a datafile(txt file)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm confused as to why my code isn't working I'm supposed to compare the numbers with eachother and then the higher number will get compared to the next number and so on and then i'll have to use worksheets to show the answer. This is what I have up until now. Grootste means biggest btw

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim A As Integer

Dim Grootste As Integer

Open "C:\Dorjee\LargestNumber.txt" For Input As #1

Do While Not EOF(1)

    Input #1, A

    If A < Grootste Then
    
    End If
Loop

Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = A

End Sub
```

Comment: There's quite a few things missing, but as its your homework I'm not going to provide you with code.  However, the first thing you should realise is that 'Grooste' starts off as zero and never changes from zero because you never assign it a value.

Answer (score 0):

### Read From a Sequential File

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim A As Integer ' *** a better variable name would e.g. be 'Huidig'
    
    Dim Grootste As Integer
    
    Open "C:\Dorjee\LargestNumber.txt" For Input As #1
    
    Do While Not EOF(1)
    
        Input #1, A
    
        ' Think about this logic and why 'Grootste' is written as the result.
        ' *** It becomes clearer if you use a better variable name than 'A'.
        If A > Grootste Then
            Grootste = A
        End If
    
    Loop
    
    Close #1 ' don't forget to close the file!
    
    Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = Grootste

End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

- Study this and implement some of the ideas into the *Quick Fix* but not before you fully understand them. For starters, use the 2nd `Debug.Print` line in the *Quick Fix* (adjust the variable names) to better understand what is happening.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Dorjee\LargestNumber.txt"

    ' Use 'FreeFile' to supply a file number that is not already in use.
    Dim TextFile As Long: TextFile = FreeFile
    
    Dim Current As Long
    Dim Biggest As Long
    
    Open FilePath For Input Access Read As #TextFile
    
        ' Print to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
        Debug.Print "TextFile = " & TextFile
        
        Do While Not EOF(TextFile)
            Input #TextFile, Current
            If Current > Biggest Then Biggest = Current
            ' Print to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
            Debug.Print "Current = " & Current, "Biggest = " & Biggest
        Loop
    
    Close #TextFile

    ' Write the result to cell `A1` in the first worksheet ('1')
    ' of the workbook containing this code ('ThisWorkbook').
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Biggest

End Sub
```

For the following sample data...

```
1,2
A,3
37,12
10
61
13
100
```

... the result in the Immediate window was:

```
TextFile = 1
Current = 1   Biggest = 1
Current = 2   Biggest = 2
Current = 0   Biggest = 2
Current = 3   Biggest = 3
Current = 37  Biggest = 37
Current = 12  Biggest = 37
Current = 10  Biggest = 37
Current = 61  Biggest = 61
Current = 13  Biggest = 61
Current = 100 Biggest = 100
```